# How to use vue-router and router-link to handle links dynamically created in jquery modules such a datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-router

I tried for a while to "integrate" datatables.net (https://datatables.net/) with a Vue app.

Eventually I stumbled on comments that essentially suggest not so much to try integration, but rather, leverage jquery modules as-in and "hook" them in via a mounted/created event.

So, in that vein, I have the following code nearly working

```
<template>
<table aria-describedby="feedback-history_info" role="grid" id="feedback-history" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Reviewer</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Created Date</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Project</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Reviewer</th>
            <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</template>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery'

// Require needed datatables modules
require('datatables.net')
require('datatables.net-bs')

import moment from 'moment'

export default {
    name: 'Feedback',
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    mounted() {
        $('#feedback-history').DataTable({
            "ajax": "/index.sjs?list",
            "processing": false,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "id"
                },
                {
                    "data": "created"
                },
                {
                    "data": "projectName"
                },
                {
                    "data": "reviewer"
                },
                {
                    "data": "status"
                }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return moment(parseInt(data)).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
                    },
                    "targets": 1
                },
                {
                    "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        // I want to use router-link similar to following
                        return `<router-link :to="{ name: 'FeedbackEdit', params: { feedbackId: ${ row.id } }}">${ row.projectName }</router-link>`

                        // To render as ...
                        // <a href="/edit/feedback/${row.id}">${data}</a>
                    },
                    "targets": 2
                },
                {
                    "visible": false,
                    "targets": [0]
                }
            ]
        })
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Only issue is in the rendering of links in my datatable cells. As I'm using vue-router, I need to vue-router via router-link to "handle links". (See comments in code).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did not use router-link.

Rather I used vuex and saved enough session information to the vuex store such that on page refresh I could re-render the view appropriately.

While technically this is a page refresh or "page flip" and not the reactive SPA-way of using the DOM (or shadow-DOM) to manipulate the view, it does give a near-enough experience in the absence of a better approach.